# .Net MVC Redirect after ADFS Authentication causes TempData to lose data

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, owin, adfs

**Your help will be appreicate**

In our web application, we have a method called "ExternalLogin" which is Post method in MVC Controller

```
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(FormCollection collection)
{
    //Here we set bunch of Temp Data (I know it is bad but it is what it is)
    var ovm = TempData["optionsVm"];
    ovm.Prop1 = "SomeValue";
    ovm.Prop2 = "SomeOtherValue";
    .
    .
    .

    //then we assign back 
    TempData["optionsVm"] = ovm;

    //we do then ADFS Authentication Challenge as below and it works
    var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    string  provider = "ADFSProvider";
    //ctx.Authentication.SignOut();
    ctx.Authentication.Challenge(
    new AuthenticationProperties
    {
    RedirectUri = 
Url.Action("**LoginCallbackBerkleyMarineAdfs**", "Account", new { provider })
                },
                provider);
   return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}

public ActionResult LoginCallbackBerkleyMarineAdfs(FormCollection collection)
{
   //Here TempData["optionsVm"] is null
}
```

I have used TempData.Keep("optionsVm") and TempData.Peek("optionsVm") in External Login method before Redirect from ADFS but to no avail.

It works sometime and it does not work other times. And really is pain.

Hope I get answer from you awesome guys. Thank you.

-------------More info on how TempData["OptionsVm"] is set up and read

```
 @{
        QuickQuoteForm optionsVm = (QuickQuoteForm)TempData["optionsVm"]; 
    } 
    <form id="ins-details" action="ExternalLogin" ...> 
        @Html.Hidden("equipmentDeductible", optionsVm.Deductible) 
        @{TempData["optionsVm"] = optionsVm;} 
    <form/>
```

Here when Form Gets Posted, it goes to External Login Method in original Question

Comment: Where is the object being instantiated? This line `var ovm = TempData["optionsVm"];` gets the object from `TempData`, but in order for that to work, there needs to be an instance of the object created somewhere else. It might also help if you post the definition of whatever that object (or struct) is.

Comment: NightOwl888, I appreciate your reply. Well I did not put where TempData["optionsVm"] coming from because by logging it, we know that TempData["optionsVm"] is NOT NULL and HAS ALL THE VALUES we need BEFORE REDIRECTION. After Redirection, it is gone.

Comment: It's not possible for anyone to answer the question unless you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Of course, nobody can reproduce this issue if they can't see how you are setting the value. `TempData` clears whenever you read it, so you need to show all of the places where you are setting and reading `TempData["optionsVm"]` in order to make any sense of this.

Comment: And both methods are in Account Controller. So all code is in Same Controller .cs class. Just an FYI.

Comment: The `TempData` value is cleared *when it is read*. It doesn't matter which controller reads it or if it is before or after the redirect. There is not enough information to answer this because we cannot see the whole picture.

Comment: @{QuickQuoteForm optionsVm = 
                     (QuickQuoteForm)TempData["optionsVm"];  }             
    <form id="ins-details" action="ExternalLogin" ...>                                          
        @Html.Hidden("equipmentDeductible", optionsVm.Deductible)
        @{TempData["optionsVm"] = optionsVm;}           
    <form/>                                                                                                 Here when Form Gets Posted, it goes to External Login Method in original Question

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the additional info, don't post code in comments.

Comment: Sorry yes I should have done it. My bad. It is there now. Thank you NightOwl888